# jQuery Mobile and anchor links requesting wrong page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have developed a rails application the main feature of which is a business search page which functions by showing a page of business results and a form which allows the user to further search/filter the results.

Recently I have implemented a mobile interface to this application using jQuery Mobile with the following setup:

The business results page is that it has two div's with a data-role of "page". The first one is the actual page full of results which a user sees when they visit, the second jQuery Mobile page has the HTML id "search-form" and contains the form fields necessary to filter the results.

In the header bar of the first page there is a button that links to #search-form with a data-rel of dialog.

This works perfectly if someone goes directly to site.com/businesses and then clicks the link, jQuery Mobile properly loads site.com/businesses#search-form into the modal dialog and the worm works, however if they begin their browsing session on any other page, the dialog always contains the content of their original page.

For example if they come to the site at site.com/someotherpage then somehow navigate to site.com/someotherpage#/businesses and click the filter button, jQuery Mobile incorrectly requests and populates the dialog with the content site.com/someotherpage#search-form

I've tried changing the filter link from #search-form to actually hard-code the full absolute path to the current page with #search-form and nothing works.

Thanks in advance, I'm going crazy with this one! It's the only thing preventing me from deploying our mobile version.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some code? Maybe the page(s) HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. Any buttons placed in #thirdPage will be dolled up nicely by jQuery, but they create their popups from the first page loaded by the user. Also, the back button on the dialog will point back at that first page.

One button (as below) is loaded in the static page, but the same applies to dynamically created buttons that I inserted via the pagebeforecreate event.

I was starting to think that all popups should be placed in the html file for the first page that users arrive at. But that did not help and it would be rather awkward.

By the way, testing in Chrome on desktop it works fine. It's only on my Android that the problem occurs. But that is most likely for the same reason mentioned earlier: on Chrome I will load page three itself, whereas on Android I will arrive via pages one and two.

Another peculiarity is that when testing in Chrome on desktop, the pagebeforecreate() event that I attached to #thirdPage is called *again*, even though the dialog is completely outside the #thirdPage element and does not have any custom events attached by me. This second call to pagebeforecreate() does not happen on the Android.

One more funny thing: the HTML page with these problems has been given a < base > element by jQueryMobile with an href attribute that does not end in html. All other pages do get that ".html" at the end. Weird.

```
  <html>
     <body>
      <div id="thirdPage" data-role="page" data-url="third">
       <a href="#desiredPopup" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Give me the popup</a>
      </div>
      <div id="desiredPopup" data-role="dialog" data-url="purchase" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#thirdPage" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back">Back to page "three"</a>
      </div>
     <body>
  <html>
```